# what is the meaning of the characters using with preg_replace in php

Tags: php

i know that preg_replace function in php — Perform a regular expression search and replace and Searches subject for matches to pattern and replaces them with replacement, Ex:

```
<?php
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/quick/';
$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'bear';
$replacements[1] = 'black';
$replacements[0] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```

The result will be :

> The bear black slow jumps over the lazy dog.

**but** i have another Example that i didn't understand the characters in search and pattern, can someone please tell me what happen here?:

```
<?php
$patterns = array ('/(19|20)(\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/',
                   '/^\s*{(\w+)}\s*=/');
$replace = array ('\3/\4/\1\2', '$\1 =');
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, '{startDate} = 1999-5-27');
?>
```

The result will be:

> $startDate = 5/27/1999

**Thank you**

Comment: [I suggest you start learning about regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: @sam Its string which undergoes search and replace operation

Comment: I just hate how bad **Some** of the users here are ... they just doing the Vote down always for normal questions like this..... where the new programmers need always support ...

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you to asnwer

Comment: @shashi Thanks man

Comment: You may also find [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) useful, not just for testing regular expressions, but for providing an explanation of what they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need take a crash course of [PHP style PCRE regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). But anyway, here is a short summary:

- `()` will cause anything inside to match as a group. This is especially convenient if you need to use this value in the replace later on, but can have other uses as well.
- `(19|20)` matches a group consisting of either the number 19 och the number 20
- `(\d{2})` matches a group consisting of two `{2}` numbers `\d`
  (). `\d` will match a character in the range 0-9.
- `{m,n}` will match the previous character or group somewhere between m and n times. `{m}` will match only m times, `{m,}` will match at least m times
- `(\d{1,2})` matches a group consisting of somewhere between 1 and 2 (i.e. 1 or 2, as there is nothing in between) numbers
- `-` matches a minus character...

For the other expression:

- `^` in the start of an expression will match the beginning of a line (`$` at the end of an expression would match the end of a line)
- `\s*` will match any number (inluding 0) of white space characters (`\s`).
- `\w+` will match a string of any word characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _) at any length but at least 1 character long

As for the replace, the `\3` will match the third group `()` in the pattern, the `\4` will match the fourth group, the `\1` will match the first group and the `\2` will match the second group.

Comment: I just hate how bad **Some** of the users here are ... they just doing the Vote down always for normal questions like this..... where the new programmers need always support ... , anyway really thanks man for your kind to describe that.